# How to create import of csv file using civicrm entity?

Tags: wordpress, data-import

I want to create a csv file import action using the civicrm entity. Can you tell me how this is done? Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: confused by your tags - isn't CiviCRM Entity a Drupal thing?

Comment: no, My crm is tied to WordPress :)

Comment: I think maybe you need to give a bit more detail. There is information about importing various things from csv files in the documentation

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/importing-data-into-civicrm/) explain what you need?  If not, please clarify the question.

Comment: 'civicrm entity' is a concept widely used for Drupal CiviCRM Entity module so your use of the term has confused folk :-). If you need an importer that does stuff that the core tools do not do, then take a look at https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport